# PHP convert 24-bit colors to 4-bit

Tags: php, colors, gd

Background, I am converting images to ascii art. This works perfectly and even works with 24-bit color, converting the colors to the right rgb values. However, I now want to render the ascii art in 4-bit color palette rather than 24-bit.

How do I convert 24-bit colors to 4-bit with PHP?

More specifically, I have the standard IRC color pallet which I need to convert any given Hexidecimal or RGB value to. It is preferred that the colors match as best as possible when converted to the 4-bit color.

Other ideas I have had on this are to convert the image itself to a 4-bit palette (using GD, which is what I use to read in the colors right now) before trying to grab colors off of it. And another idea might be to define a color range for each of the following color and just check that the given 24-bit color is in the range, however I wouldn't know how to get the ranges for all colors into that palette.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, despite the wonderful suggestions surrounding imagemagick I found a good solution using straight php.  I was able to calculate the closest color through the use of delta E 2000 with a modified version of php-color-difference library found on github, here is my fork: https://github.com/nalipaz/php-color-difference

The pertinent example is:

```
<?php
include('lib/color_difference.class.php');

$palette = array(
  '00' => array(255, 255, 255),
  '01' => array(0, 0, 0),
  '02' => array(0, 0, 139),
  '03' => array(0, 128, 0),
  '04' => array(255, 0, 0),
  '05' => array(139, 0, 0),
  '06' => array(128, 0, 128),
  '07' => array(255, 165, 0),
  '08' => array(255, 255, 0),
  '09' => array(50, 205, 50),
  '10' => array(0, 128, 128),
  '11' => array(173, 216, 230),
  '12' => array(0, 0, 255),
  '13' => array(255, 105, 180),
  '14' => array(128, 128, 128),
  '15' => array(211, 211, 211),
);

$color_rgb = array(255, 255, 128);
$color_delta_e = new color_difference($color_rgb);
$match_index = $color_delta_e->getClosestMatch($palette);
$color = $palette[$match_index];
```

I am pretty happy with this solution and smaller amount of overhead.  Thanks for the suggestions guys.

Answer (score 2):

[`imagetruecolortopalette`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagetruecolortopalette.php) allows you to reduce the colours, but results can vary wildly and I don't know if there is a way of 'mapping' the colours correctly or specifying the palette.

**Test image (24-bit):**

[image: Bliss]

**Reduced to 4-bit (without dithering):**

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng('Bliss.png');
imagetruecolortopalette($img, false, 16);
imagepng($img, 'Bliss2.png');
```

[image: Bliss, without dithering]

**Reduced to 4-bit (with dithering):**

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng('Bliss.png');
imagetruecolortopalette($img, true, 16);
imagepng($img, 'Bliss3.png');
```

[image: Bliss, with dithering]

As you can see, results are far from perfect. But perhaps this is a good start for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think ImageMagick (or GraphicsMagick) can do this with the -depth option. There's a discussion of it here: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=15395

UPDATE: I should add that ImageMagick is not a PHP library, however there's a PECL wrapper (imagick) for it at http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick.

Comment: ImageMagick could become a requirement without much hassle.  I am guessing I would need to convert any jpe?g's and gifs to png's before using this right?

Comment: I think the -depth option works across formats - see http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#depth.

Comment: Looking into changing depth.  That could be helpful possibly but it doesn't account for my needing to replace the colors with colors from the above palette.  The resulting image needs to be only that of the colors in the above palette.  Perhaps if I reduce to 16 with depth change and then replace each of the 16 colors with the ones from above then it might work.  I will however need to research replacement of colors and matching each of the above colors to sensible colors in the resulting image.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `remap` to map the colours in the image to the palette of colours in your swatch. I do it at the command line like this:

```
convert image.jpg -remap palette.jpg out.jpg
```

You may, or may not want the `dither` option - check it out.

Original image is here:

[image]
and this is my `palette.jpg` (you only need a really small image, this is way too big - I will address this shortly)

[image]

and the result
[image]

You can also create your palette according to the colours you want using ImageMagick. I hand-coded the following and didn't pay too much attention, so you would want to check the RGB values in here before assuming they are correct:

```
#/bin/bash
cat<<EOF | convert txt:- palette.png
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 8,2,256,rgb
0,0: (255,255,255)
1,0: (0,0,0)
2,0: (0,0,255)
3,0: (255,255,0)
4,0: (255,0,0)
5,0: (128,128,128)
6,0: (255,105,180)
7,0: (173,216,230)
0,1: (50,205,50)
1,1: (139,0,0)
2,1: (255,165,0)
3,1: (128,0,128)
4,1: (0,0,139)
5,1: (0,128,128)
6,1: (0,128,0)
7,1: (211,211,211)
EOF
```

Basically, the script above gives ImageMagick the RGB values as text and asks it to make small 8x2 image that looks like this:

[image]

Then you would use this palette with your `remap` operation.