# Limit Color Palette using PHP

Tags: php, image, color-palette

Is there a way to limit an image to a custom color palette of 15 colors (plus transparency)? I would like to adjust the color palette of images to a specific set of colors using PHP functions.

Right now I am loading images using imagecreatefrompng(), but they contain the default RGB palette. I also have a 4x4px image with each desired color.

I have tried using imagepalettecopy(), but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
    $palette = imagecreatefrompng(public_path() . "/assets/palette2.png");
    $original = imagecreatefrompng(public_path() . '/uploads/test1.png');
    $resampled = imagecreatetruecolor(5, 5);

    imagepalettecopy($resampled, $palette);
    imagecopyresampled($resampled, $original, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, imagesx($original), imagesy($original));
    imagepalettecopy($resampled, $palette);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Mike, Have a look here...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26225594/php-convert-24-bit-colors-to-4-bit/26231236#26231236

Comment: Manually adjusting the colors was going to be my next step. I will try that now, the answer you linked provides a good guideline. Thanks!

Comment: Isnt GIF the only image format which uses a palette and not a per-pixel-color ?

Comment: Based on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics at least PNG also supports color palettes.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following to work excellently with pure PHP. Not sure how this stacks up performance-wise, but it provides the desired results:

```
    $palette = imagecreatefrompng(public_path() . "/assets/palette.png");
    $original1 = imagecreatefrompng(public_path() . '/uploads/test1.png');
    $resampled1 = imagecreatetruecolor(5, 5);
    $adjusted1 = imagecreatetruecolor(5, 5);
    imagetruecolortopalette($palette, false, 16);

    imagecopyresampled($resampled1, $original1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, imagesx($original1), imagesy($original1));

    for ($row = 0; $row < 5; $row++) {
        for ($column = 0; $column < 5; $column++) {
            $rgb1 = imagecolorat($resampled1, $column, $row);
            $color1 = imagecolorsforindex($resampled1, $rgb1);
            $closestRgb1 = imagecolorclosest($palette, $color1['red'], $color1['green'], $color1['blue']);
            $closestColor1 = imagecolorsforindex($palette, $closestRgb1);
            imagesetpixel($adjusted1, $column, $row, imagecolorallocate($adjusted1, $closestColor1['red'], $closestColor1['green'], $closestColor1['blue']));
        }
    }
```